# Firebase error when trying to download google-services.json

Tags: firebase

I have just created a new project on Firebase, and now I should download the `google-services.json`. However, when I click on the button to download, I got the following error:

```
)]}'
{
    "code":7,
    "errorSpace":"generic",
    "placeholders":{
        "trackingId":"09812391289309"
    },
    "status":403,
    "message":"backend error"
}
```

Is this a problem that Firebase is running now, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clear cache/history for the browser you're using.

Also try on different web browser or on private/incognito session will solve the problem